# Using a non-static object method with usort

Tags: php, usort

I am trying to sort an array of values using a class method.  The values are as follows

```
$agegroups = array("08","910","1112","1314","1516","1718","1999");
```

However, they can be any combination of numbers.  The values above correspond to age groups used on my site and are are defined in a database table, so I can't hard code them.  I have an object that contains an array of age group defintions like this

```
private $agegroups = array();

function __construct() {
  // retrieve data from the database
  while($data = $sth->fetch()) {
    $ag = new StdClass();
    $ag->low = $data['low'];   //stores the low end of the age group
    $ag->high = $data['high']  //stores the high end of the age group
    $this->agegroups[$data['key']] = $ag;
  }
}
```

`$data['key']` corresponds to the `$agegroups` array defined above. In the same class, I defined a sort method

```
function sort($a,$b) {
  $aAG = $this->agegroups[$a];
  $bAG = $this->agegroups[$b];

  return $aAG->low > $bAG->low ? 1 : -1;
}
```

My understanding is that usort can only use a static method. However my object needs to retrieve the values from a database, so I can't make it static.

I tried using an anonymous function with usort that could use an instance of the class defined outside the function but I get an error about an undefined object.

```
$agObj = new agegroups();
$agegroups = usort($agegroups, function($a, $b){
  global $agObj;
  return $agObj->sort($a,$b);
});
```

The error I get is **Fatal error: Call to a member function sort() on a non-object**

I release I can create a new instance of the object inside the anonymous function but I don't want to have to query the database each time.  Is there a way to use my class to sort these values?

Comment: Why can't you make the `usort()` call inside the class?

Comment: The $agegroups array comes from another datsource.

Comment: So pass the final `$agegroups` array into the function that will `usort` the array.

Comment: Your code with `global $agObj` should have worked. Are you sure there's no typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever a function is required, you can use `array(object, functionName)` to call the method on that object.

```
usort($agegroups, array($agObj, 'sort'));
```

BTW, you shouldn't assign the result of `usort` back to `agegroups`. The sorting functions modify the array in place; they return a boolean, not the reordered array.